# Thread safe bit array?

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, primes

***EDIT TO QUESTION:** Is it possible to have thread safe access to a bit array? My implementation below seems to require mutex locks which defeats the purpose of parallelizing.*

I've been tasked with creating a parallel implementation of a twin prime generator using pthreads. I decided to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes and to divide the work of marking the factors of known primes. I staggering which factors a thread gets.

For example, if there are 4 threads:
thread one marks multiples 3, 11, 19, 27...
thread two marks multiples 5, 13, 21, 29...
thread two marks multiples 7, 15, 23, 31...
thread two marks multiples 9, 17, 25, 33...

I skipped the even multiples as well as the even base numbers. I've used a bitarray, so I run it up to INT_MAX. The problem I have is at max value of 10 million, the result varies by about 5 numbers, which is how much error there is compared to a known file. The results vary all the way down to about max value of 10000, where it changes by 1 number. Anything below that is error-free.

At first I didn't think there was a need for communication between processes. When I saw the results, I added a pthread barrier to let all the threads catch up after each set of multiples. This didn't make any change. *Adding a mutex lock around the mark() function did the trick, but that slows everything down.*

Here is my code. Hoping someone might see something obvious.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#define WORDSIZE 32

struct t_data{
    int *ba;
    unsigned int val;
    int num_threads;
    int thread_id;
};  

pthread_mutex_t mutex_mark;

void  mark( int *ba, unsigned int k )
{
    ba[k/32] |= 1 << (k%32); 
}

void  mark( int *ba, unsigned int k )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_mark);
    ba[k/32] |= 1 << (k%32); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_mark);
}

void initBa(int **ba, unsigned int val)
{
    *ba = calloc((val/WORDSIZE)+1, sizeof(int));
}

void getPrimes(int *ba, unsigned int val)
{
    int i, p;
    p = -1;

    for(i = 3; i<=val; i+=2){
            if(!isMarked(ba, i)){
                    if(++p == 8){
                        printf(" \n");
                        p = 0;
                    }
                    printf("%9d", i);
            }   
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void markTwins(int *ba, unsigned int val)
{
    int i;
    for(i=3; i<=val; i+=2){
        if(!isMarked(ba, i)){
            if(isMarked(ba, i+2)){
                mark(ba, i);
            }

        }
    }
}

void *setPrimes(void *arg)
{
    int *ba, thread_id, num_threads, status;
    unsigned int val, i, p, start;
    struct t_data *data = (struct t_data*)arg;
    ba = data->ba;
    thread_id = data->thread_id;
    num_threads = data->num_threads;
    val = data->val;

    start = (2*(thread_id+2))-1; // stagger threads

    i=3; 
    for(i=3; i<=sqrt(val); i+=2){ 
        if(!isMarked(ba, i)){
            p=start;
            while(i*p <= val){
                    mark(ba, (i*p));
                p += (2*num_threads); 
            }       
        }       
    }
    return 0;
}

void usage(char *filename)
{
    printf("Usage: \t%s [option] [arg]\n", filename);
    printf("\t-q generate #'s internally only\n");
    printf("\t-m [size] maximum size twin prime to calculate\n");
    printf("\t-c [threads] number of threads\n");
    printf("Defaults:\n\toutput results\n\tsize = INT_MAX\n\tthreads = 1\n");
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int *ba, i, num_threads, opt, output;
    unsigned int val;

    output = 1;
    num_threads = 1;
    val = INT_MAX;  

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "qm:c:")) != -1){
        switch (opt){
            case 'q': output = 0;
                break;
            case 'm': val = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'c': num_threads = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            default: 
                usage(argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    struct t_data data[num_threads];    
    pthread_t thread[num_threads];
    pthread_attr_t attr;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_mark, NULL);

    initBa(&ba, val);   

    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);    

    for(i=0; i < num_threads; i++){
        data[i].ba = ba;
        data[i].thread_id = i;
        data[i].num_threads = num_threads;
        data[i].val = val;
        if(0 != pthread_create(&thread[i],
                                &attr,
                                setPrimes,
                                (void*)&data[i])){
            perror("Cannot create thread");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }

    markTwins(ba, val);
    if(output)
        getPrimes(ba, val); 

    free(ba);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I got rid of the barrier and added a mutex_lock to the mark function. Output is accurate now, but now more than one thread slows it down. Any suggestions on speeding it up?

Comment: Some processors have set/reset instructions that can apply a bitmask to a memory location in one, atomic operation.  You may wish to check your instruction set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your currently implementation of mark is *correct*, but the locking is extremely coarse-grained - there's only one lock for your entire array.  This means that your threads are constantly contending for that lock.

One way of improving performance is to make the lock finer-grained: each 'mark' operation only requires exclusive access to a single integer within the array, so you could have a mutex for each array entry:

```
struct bitarray
{
    int *bits;
    pthread_mutex_t *locks;
};

struct t_data
{
    struct bitarray ba;
    unsigned int val;
    int num_threads;
    int thread_id;
};

void initBa(struct bitarray *ba, unsigned int val)
{
    const size_t array_size = val / WORDSIZE + 1;
    size_t i;

    ba->bits = calloc(array_size, sizeof ba->bits[0]);
    ba->locks = calloc(array_size, sizeof ba->locks[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_init(&ba->locks[i], NULL);
    }
}

void mark(struct bitarray ba, unsigned int k)
{
    const unsigned int entry = k / 32;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&ba.locks[entry]);
    ba.bits[entry] |= 1 << (k%32); 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ba.locks[entry]);
}
```

Note that your algorithm has a race-condition: consider the example where `num_threads = 4`, so Thread 0 starts at 3, Thread 1 starts at 5 and Thread 2 starts at 7.  It is possible for Thread 2 to execute fully, marking every multiple of 7 and then start again at 15, *before* Thread 0 or Thread 1 get a chance to mark 15 as a multiple of 3 or 5.  Thread 2 will then do useless work, marking every multiple of 15.

---

Another alternative, if your compiler supports Intel-style atomic builtins, is to use those instead of a lock:

```
void mark(int *ba, unsigned int k)
{
    __sync_or_and_fetch(&ba[k/32], 1U << k % 32); 
}
```

Comment: Wow, can I really use an array of UINT_MAX/32 mutex variables? Do you know how much space they take up? (sorry, I mentioned running it to INT_MAX but I really meant UINT_MAX)

Comment: In regards to the race condition. All the threads work off the same current prime. It's the multiples that are split between the processes. I wasn't very clear about that. For example for two processes, if the current known prime is 3, process one marks 3*3, 3*11, 3*19, 3*27..., process 2 marks 3*5, 3*13, 3*21, 3*29...and so on. I'm wondering now though now if this would defeat the purpose of locking each element, as their all going to be overlapping quite a bit. Might be better to have all the primes for 2-sqrt(max) predetermined, then stagger or block separate the known primes instead?

Comment: @MatthewTanner: The size depends on your implementation (eg on Linux x86 glibc, `pthread_mutex_t` is 24 bytes).  You can of course choose any granularity you like, from one mutex per array entry right up to one mutex for the entire array - just divide by `WORDSIZE * N` instead of `WORDSIZE` when calculating the mutex index and mutex array size.  If you predetermine the primes up to sqrt(max) then you could probably just give each thread its own private bitarray (presuming you have the memory to spare for that) and combine the bitarrays at the end, no locking needed at all.

Comment: Got it, thank you. I've got the primes predetermined up to sqrt(max). I'm going to separate the processes as much as possible, probably by splitting up the predetermined primes into blocks, then play with the number of locks. I thought of the individual bit arrays, but that's definitely going to limit my amount of threads.

Comment: @MatthewTanner: There's another alternative if your compiler supports the Intel-style atomic builtins, as gcc does.  See the updated answer.  You will still get a lot of cacheline ping-ponging if your threads are all stomping around the same area of shared memory though, so the alternatives that keep them spread apart will still perform better.

Answer (score 1):

Your `mark()` funciton is not threadsafe - if two threads try to set bits within the same `int` location one might overwrite with 0 a bit that was just set by another thread.

Comment: I got rid of the barrier and added a mutex_lock to the mark function. It's accurate, but now it gets slower with every additional thread.